# Start Quicktime Player recording while in Split View mode

Tags: macos, quicktime, split-view, screen-recording

I have two apps side by side in Split View mode and would like to record that. Is there a way to start a QuickTime Player recording while being in Split View mode with two apps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a on a new desktop, and later trim it.

https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/quicktime-player/qtpf2115f6fd/mac

If it is only screen, not audio, you can even use <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> to record the screen in most circumstances.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand. What do you mean exactly by "trim it" ? Do you mean I should start the recording on a new desktop, and then switch to Split View mode ?

Comment: yes, see updated answer